# Mongodb Connection pooling issue with multi core system for a MEAN stack application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a quad core system, where I am trying to run an application on the MEAN stack. I have set the poolSize as 5 when I use the mongoose driver. But I see more than 40 connections open in the monogod log. Without clusters I notice that the poolSize works correctly, I see only 5 connections open.

**Connection issues with clusters**

```
2016-03-28T16:32:00.404+0530 I NETWORK  [conn14] end connection 127.0.0.1:33925 (31 connections now open)
2016-03-28T16:32:00.404+0530 I NETWORK  [conn13] end connection 127.0.0.1:33924 (31 connections now open)
2016-03-28T16:32:00.404+0530 I NETWORK  [conn4] end connection
```

My server.js code is as follows

```
 var app = express();

if (cluster.isMaster) {
for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
}
cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(');
    cluster.fork();
});
}
else {
/**
 * Connect to MongoDB.
 */
dalUtils.connectToDatabase(secrets.env);

/**
 * Express configuration.
 */
}
```

My dalutils code is as follows

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var secrets = require('../../config/secrets');

exports.connectToDatabase = function(environment){
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
  console.error('MongoDB Connection Error. Please make sure that MongoDB is running.');
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('Connected!!!');
});


switch (environment) {
    case 'development':         
        mongoose.connect(secrets.dev_db,{ server: { poolSize: 5  }});
        break;
    case 'production' :
        mongoose.connect(secrets.prod_db);
        break;
    default :
        mongoose.connect(secrets.dev_db);
        break;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the issue was not in the code mentioned above. I was using mongo-store and instead of using the mongooseConnection property, I had used url. This led to another 20 connections opening instead of the default connection Pools

```
 store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
```